# discord.py/How to get selected options in slash command?

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

How can I use the button displayed by a slash command to get the selected option for that slash command?

I'm using a module called disnake and I think the way to get it is the same as discord.py.

> ```
> class ButtonView(disnake.ui.View):
>     def __init__(self):
>         super().__init__(timeout=None)
>
>     @disnake.ui.button(label="button", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red)
>     async def first_button(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
>         pass
>
> @bot.slash_command() 
> async def test(inter, id:str):
>     await inter.send("slash command", view=ButtonView())
> ```

```
@bot.slash_command() 
async def test(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, id:str):
    print(f'this is option{inter.options}') 

#Using this code i was able to get the options during the slash command but i don't know how to get the #options if i use the button
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're creating your own view - you can just add a parameter to the constructor and pass that when you create it.

```py
class ButtonView(disnake.ui.View):
    # add 'options' as a parameter when we create an instance of the class
    def __init__(self, options):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        # store the options as a class variable
        self.options = options

    @disnake.ui.button(label="button", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def first_button(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        # access the options
        print(self.options)


# then when you create the view in your command
@bot.slash_command() 
async def test(inter, id:str):
    # give the view class the options of this slash command
    my_view = ButtonView(inter.options)
    await inter.send("slash command", view=my_view)
```

This is pretty standard [python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) stuff so you might want to read up on it. The view won't contain any information about the command that created it, *unless* you pass that information along to the View class like we did here.

Comment: However, in that case, you can only get the option that was expected at that time, and an error will occur if you use the code "bot.add_view(ButtonView)". I want to get it by pressing a button

Comment: There's no way for a button to magically know what options a user selected in a slash command. The button doesn't maintain any information about _why_ it was created, it just _is_. You have to pass that information to the view/button class and use it yourself. If the view is meant to be permanent then you need to find another way around it - but you're not using custom IDs for the UI objects so view permanence wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: you are right, custom_id was not here. I'm currently trying to write codes where a button press grants a role, and I'm currently saving that option in a text file and granting the role from there. Is there a better way to accomplish this?